# Braintree, How to use application generated ids with a new customer

Tags: java, braintree

So I have simple java based server backend. I would like to create an empty customer and use an id that is generated in my application, not the id that is assigned by braintree. I tried to use this approach:

```
String testId = "12345678";

log.info("Create customer with id: " + testId);
    CustomerRequest customerRequest = new CustomerRequest()
            .customerId(testId)
            .firstName("Martin")
            .lastName("Mojko");
braintreeGateway.customer().create(customerRequest);
```

However, the setter `customerId` is ignored and braintree assigns different id to this customer.
It is there any way to use own ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You should use [`.id`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/java#id) instead of `.customerId` to assign your generated ID to your customer. The request will look something like this:

```
CustomerRequest request = new CustomerRequest()
  .id(testId)
  .firstName("Martin")
  .lastName("Mojko");

Result<Customer> result = gateway.customer().create(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to store a mapping between your IDs and theirs yourself.

This is very typical of 3rd party services everywhere. After all, the ID you supply to them may not match their ID generation scheme or may already be in use so they can't just use it themselves.

Comment: yea thats the only solution I see